# Why am I getting a compilation error per statement since a specific line?

Tags: java

So I am doing a java course on programmr as I am trying to learn. The question is asking to write code that checks if a substring is in a string. This is the default code that compiles fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rats {

    public boolean ratSmeller(String line) {
        ///{
               //write your code here
         //start



               //end
        ///}        
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word and we will tell you if it contains the string 'rat' in it: ");
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        Rats rats = new Rats();
        System.out.println("Output: ");
        System.out.println(rats.ratSmeller(word));
    }
}
```

And this is my finished code that is giving me a ton of errors:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rats {

    public boolean ratSmeller(String line) {
        ///{
               //write your code here
         //start
        if (line.contains("rat")){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
        }
               //end
        ///}        
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word and we will tell you if it contains the string 'rat' in it: ");
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        Rats rats = new Rats();
        System.out.println("Output: ");
        System.out.println(rats.ratSmeller(word));
    }
}
```

These are the erros I am receiving:

```
Main.java:20: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public static void main(String args[]) {
                  ^
Main.java:22: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        System.out.println("Enter a word and we will tell you if it contains the string 'rat' in it: ");
        ^
Main.java:23: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        ^
Main.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        Rats rats = new Rats();
        ^
Main.java:25: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        System.out.println("Output: ");
        ^
Main.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        System.out.println(rats.ratSmeller(word));
        ^
Main.java:27: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
```

Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: Please use a IDE like Eclipse, that will help you a ton. Check the body of your `ratSmeller` method.

Comment: Before asking, why don't you check yourself the issues? (It took me very little to track down the same problem mentioned in Luiggi's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain what's happening?

You have compilation errors due to a bad braces `{}` enclosing. The problem is here:

```
public boolean ratSmeller(String line) {
    if (line.contains("rat")){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    } //this brace is destroying your current code, remove it
}
```

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot, I tried looking at the braces and didn't see an issue. Thank you for the quick response it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user3737992 try using an IDE next time. For starters, use Doctor Java, or you can directly start with Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea (disclaimer: I'm not seller of any of these products nor I'm associated with these companies, just a happy user).

Comment: I'll throw in a recommendation for NetBeans, which I find more intuitive than Eclipse.  (Haven't tried IntelliJ.)

Comment: @adv12 I've used Netbeans and I'm not a happy user for that technology :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I wish i could, unfortunately I can't download and install an IDE on my work computer which is where I do most of this learning.

Comment: @user3737992 then use an online IDE like http://www.ideone.com/

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I actually did use that, it didn't tell me anything different though so I was still stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` in the wrong place. See `/* <-- remove this */` comment below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rats {

    public boolean ratSmeller(String line) {
        ///{
               //write your code here
         //start
        if (line.contains("rat")){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
        }
               //end
        ///}        
    } /* <-- remove this */

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word and we will tell you if it contains the string 'rat' in it: ");
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        Rats rats = new Rats();
        System.out.println("Output: ");
        System.out.println(rats.ratSmeller(word));
    }
}
```